# PHP Unable to create directory

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am running PHP 7.2 on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I am trying to have a PHP script create a directory, but this is failing for some reason, and I am unable to figure out why. The permissions to the script are 777 and to the folders it is attempting to write to 705.

I have tried chowning the directory to the nobody group and this still does not work. Here is the code I am trying to make the directory:

```
if (!file_exists($sharexdir)) {
    mkdir($sharexdir, 0705, true);
    copy($_POST['type'].'/index.html', $sharexdir.'index.html');
}
```

I have added the following to test:

```
if(!mkdir('./img/12345/54321/', 0705, true)) {
    echo 'Couldnt create folder';
}
if (!file_exists($sharexdir)) {
    echo 'No exist';
}
```

I receive a Couldn't create folder and No Exist reply on POST

Comment: Who's the owner of the parent directory? I.e. the directory you're trying to create this directory in

Comment: I've made it to nobody through `chown nobody /directory`

Comment: Assuming (based on the tags) you're running this via Apache, what happens if you chown it to www-data?

Comment: Still comes up with the same replies on POST request.

Comment: Is your error level set to show warnings? If so, is there anything in the PHP/Apache error logs? mkdir should spit out a warning if there's a permissions problem, which is (in my experience) the most likely problem.

Comment: I do have error reporting set to 0 at the very top of the the PHP. Let me try change that and I'll update you with the error

Comment: `mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/grounddug/cdn/upload.php on line 22` - This is the mkdir shown on my first codeblock @frozenjakalope

Comment: Bingo. It's the permissions in the parent dir causing the problem - either there's an owner mismatch with the user that executes the PHP script or the permissions on the parent dir are too restrictive. If chown'ing `cdn` to www-data didn't fix it and the perms for that folder are definitely 7xx, I'd look into what user Apache is running PHP as. It's www-data by default, but then the chown would definitely have fixed it.

Comment: That's so odd, I've tried giving it root access and even then it doesn't have permissions to create a directory, do you have any thoughts on what I could do to fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212086/discussion-between-frozenjakalope-and-generic-nerd).